# For an Amazon S3 bucket deployment from GitHub how do I fix the error AccessControlListNotSupported: The bucket does not allow ACLs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, deployment, continuous-deployment

I have the following access policy set on an IAM user in my AWS account. The policy references the bucket name which is "xo-staging".

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AccessToGetBucketLocation",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AccessToWebsiteBuckets",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xo-staging",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xo-staging/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AccessToCloudfront",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudfront:GetInvalidation",
                "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm deploying a Gatsby application from my local machine to Github where I am using Github Actions to run a build and deploy script.

In my package.json file I have set "deploy" to the value of `gatsby-plugin-s3 deploy --yes; export AWS_PAGER=\"\"; aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id E5FDMTLPHUTLTL --paths '/*';`  in my workflows.yml file I have set "deploy" to `npm run deploy`.

In Github my build succeeds but my deploy fails. The error I get tells me ***"AccessControlListNotSupported: The bucket does not allow ACLs".***

I've checked the actual bucket permissions in AWS and tried selecting different options, but always the same error message returns. In other words, I have tried removing all blocks on public access and ACLs but still the problem persists.

Please can someone suggest what I might need to change to get this full deploy working?

Answer (score 167):

Adding Screenshots to the answer provided by @rudieros

1. Go to Bucket > Permissions Tab
   [image: AWS Bucket Config]
2. Scroll to `Object Ownership` and click on Edit.
   [image]
3. Change the settings as below.
   [image: Edit S3 Ownership ACL]

Comment: Was an update
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-s3-object-ownership-simplify-access-management-data-s3/

Comment: ACLs disabled has this description: _All objects in this bucket are owned by this account. Access to this bucket and its objects is specified using only policies._


Does this imply that there is a policy based way to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: Is there an option to let an S3 client (e.g. the Amazon PHP SDK one) not call any ACL related code? And to thereby not having to modify the bucket policy?

Comment: I don't like this answer because by doing so, you're transferring the ownership of uploaded files to the object writer. It means that in a case where you give access to another account to write to this bucket, you're not the owner of the files but the uploader is.

Answer (score 49):

Go to your bucket, into the **Permissions** tab, find **Object Ownership** and click **Edit**. Select **ACLs enabled** and read carefully AWS warnings about potential security risks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AWS SAM:

```
Resources:
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub fleteo-${Environment}-bucket
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: false
        IgnorePublicAcls: false
        BlockPublicPolicy: false
        RestrictPublicBuckets: false
      OwnershipControls:
        Rules:
          - ObjectOwnership: BucketOwnerPreferred
```