# Getting AccessControlListNotSupported: The bucket does not allow ACLs error from S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, github-actions, acl

Trying to execute a GitHub Actions workflow that creates a xlsx file and upload the file to S3 bucket and getting the error:

> AccessControlListNotSupported: The bucket does not allow ACLs

The error pops up when the GitHub Actions workflow is executed, however when I execute it from the localhost environment it works normally.

I've already defined permissions for "Object Ownership, Access control list (ACL), Bucket policy.

Bucket Policy

[image: Bucket policy]

Access Control List (ACL)

[image: Access Control List(ACL)]

Object Ownership

[image: Object Ownership]

Block public access (bucket settings)

[image: Block public access (bucket settings)]

```js
const aclHeader = 'public-read';

return client.send(
  new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: filename,
    Body: xlsxContent,
    ContentType:
      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    ACL: aclHeader,
  })
);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70603995/10692493

Answer (score 0):

Verify you have not put an enforcement mechanism in place that could be blocking the use of ACLs despite your settings.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ensure-object-ownership.html